# Setting minimum fixed size QCustomPlot bar graph inside QSplitter

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I am using `QCustomPlot` to plot a bar graph. There are two such bar graphs horizontally arranged inside a `QSplitter` (which can be dragged). On dragging the splitter horizontally, the bar graphs resize and scale to the point that the axes labels start to overlap. I have a parent `QWidget` which contains a `QScrollArea` which ultimately contains the plot. This widget is added to the `QSplitter`.

```
QWidget* topLeftParent = new QWidget;
topLeftParent->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
QScrollArea *topLeftScrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
topLeftScrollArea->setWidget(energyGraph->GetPlot());
topLeftScrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
topLeftScrollArea->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
topLeftParent->layout()->addWidget(topLeftScrollArea);
m_pTopLeftHorizontalSplitter->setMinimumWidth(500);
m_pTopLeftHorizontalSplitter->addWidget(topLeftParent);
```

### Existing Behaviour:

On dragging the splitter horizontally, the bar graphs expand/shrink horizontally till the axes tick labels overlap and ultimately at a very small value of width, the horizontal scrollbar appears, which is useless. Same is the case for resizing the window as well.

### Required Behavior

However, I seek a different behavior. I want the bar graphs to be horizontally scrollable without them resizing on dragging the splitter i.e. dragging the splitter left/right should reveal more/less of the graphs, and *not* resize them

### Queries

1. How do I specify that the bar graph should have a minimum size and expand from that depending on the number of ticks on x-axis?
2. How do I stop the plot from automatically expanding/shrinking?

### What I have tried so far

I have tried setting minimum size for the plot, but it does not work.
I have also tried specifying the stretch factor for the splitter to 0, but that also has *no* effect i.e. the behavior is auto resizing bar graphs in both the cases with scrollbar appearing too late.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the required behavior you can use the `QTableWidget` widget. You need to:

1. Create a `QTableWidget` widget with two columns  and and one row.
2. Set the `QScrollArea` widget as the parent of the `QTableWidget` widget.
3. Hide the horizontal and vertical headers. To do so set `horizontalHeaderVisible` and `verticalHeaderVisible` to `false`.
4. Add `QCustomPlot` widgets into the table using the `setCellWidget(int row, int column, QWidget * widget)` method.

Comment: This might work but I also need the splitter expansion facility i.e. I should be able to then drag the cell borders to resize the view (not the plot). Is that possible because that is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it was solved: I just had to call the `setWidgetResizable` with `false` for the scroll area and now I have a permanent scrollbar and the custom plot does not resize while dragging the splitter.

Answer (score 0):

Find if you have this line:

```
ui->my_plot->setInteractions(QCP::iRangeZoom | QCP::iRangeDrag);
```

And edit it to whatever you want, for example just range zoom:

```
ui->my_plot->setInteractions(QCP::iRangeZoom);
```